# Multiple variable declarations

Tags: vmware, powershell-3.0

I have a script which I use it for multiple tasks like

1. Create Folder in vSphere
2. Create ResourcePools
3. Create a VM (VMware)
4. Configure IP/DNS
5. Add it to domain, …

For this I need multiple inputs needed like VM name, vCenter Server name, userid, password, etc. How do I declare the input variables externally (separate from Main script) and also make it generic in look.

I tried using below procedure but it gives me call depth overflow error.

`VARIABLE_DECLARATION.ps1`:

```
VariableDeclaration = @{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [int]$CustomerCID = '10000';
    [string]$CustomerName = "ABCcorp";
    [string]$vCenterName = "vCenter.ABCcorp.com";
    [string]$vCenterUserName = "administrator@vsphere.local";
    [string]$vCenterPassword = "ABCcorp123!";
    [string]$CustomerPODLocation = "VW1";
    [string]$DatacenterName = "ABCcorpDC";
    [string]$ClusterName = "ABCcorpcluster";
    [string]$InfraResourcePoolName = ($CustomerCID + "-" + $CustomerName + "-" + "Infrastructure");
    [string]$DesktopResourcePoolName = ($CustomerCID + "-" + $CustomerName + "-" + "Desktop");
    [string]$CustomerFolderName = ($CustomerCID + "-" + $CustomerName);
    [string]$ConnectionType = "xConnect";
    [int]$VLANID = '237';
    [string]$CustomerDVPortGroupName = ($CustomerPODLocation + "-" + $ConnectionType  + "-" + $CustomerCID + "-" + $CustomerName + "-" + $VLANID);
    [int]$NumberofPorts = '1024';
    [string]$AD1computername = ($CustomerCID + "-RADSVR01-v" + $CustomerName + ".vdi");
    [string]$AD2computername = ($CustomerCID + "-RADSVR02-v" + $CustomerName + ".vdi");
    [string]$sourcetemplate = "BaseWin2012R2";
    [string]$description = "ABCcorp Infra Systems";
    [string]$OSCustomizationspec = "ABCcorp";
    [string]$AD1IP = "10.0.0.10";
    [string]$AD2IP = "10.0.0.11";
    [string]$SNM = "255.255.255.0";
    [string]$DG = "10.0.0.1";
    [string]$DNS = "10.0.0.2";
    [string]$HostUsername = "root";
    [string]$HostPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "ABCcorp123" -AsPlainText -Force);
    [string]$HostCredential = (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $HostUsername, $HostPassword)
  )
}
```

Comment: could you please help me with a small example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell parameter definition doesn't work that way. Create a function for each of your tasks with the parameters required for that specific function/task. To make the functions available put them in a script and [dot-source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) it, or put them in a [module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340.aspx) and [load that module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module).

Example for dot-sourcing a PowerShell script:

`vm-functions.ps1`:

```
function New-VSphereFolder {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$FolderName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$vCenterName = "vCenter.ABCcorp.com",

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$Username = "administrator@vsphere.local",

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$Password = "ABCcorp123!",

        ...
    )

    ...
}

function New-ResourcePool {
    ...
}
```

Dot-source the script the script to make the functions available in the current context, then use whichever function you need:

```
PS C:\> . C:\path\to\vm-functions.ps1
PS C:\> New-VSphereFolder -FolderName ...
...
```

For further information about parameters in PowerShell scripts/functions see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters).

Comment: Thanks much , and whatif I want to include Try-Catch for error/exception handling ? How and where do I include that ?

Comment: Please post a new question describing which errors you want to handle. Include a [mcve] of the code you currently have and describe what about the code doesn't work as you expected. If you're looking for a PowerShell tutorial please consult your preferred search engine.